# How to set full pages printed in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: acumatica

I got the issue in the printing pages in Acumatica (actually the SO644000 in Sale Order => Pick List, the content of the report only fill half of the pages:

[image]

This is the SO644000 in Report Designer[image]

Could you guy show me how to setup it print Portrait with content fill all the page like the default landscape (I don't use landscape)

Thanks you for your support

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue.

Open the original unmodified report, go into the Layout section, change Landscape to 'False' and then select PaperKind, this should set the report size for you:
[image]

**EDIT** If default A4 paper kind doesn't work for your use case, use custom size, select A4 PaperKind first to set PaperSize, then switch to Custom paper kind and set Width to PaperSize Width:
[image]

Choose PDF report output:
[image]

The end result should fit on A4 paper in portrait mode:
[image]

Set PrintAtBottom = True for sections you want to display at the bottom of the page:
[image]

Comment: Thanks you it get better but not done. As my picture it only fill about 40% fo the page. Now with you help it fill about 60% of the page. Can you help me fill 100% of the page.

Comment: It could be a paper format issue, in my screenshot I used a 'Letter' format which is standard in North-America. Try to confirm the paper size of your printer and choose that as PaperKind. As a last resort you could manually change Width/Height of the paper to fit the output.

Comment: I already try this but still didn't work out. Can you try to setup the full fill A4 portrait in Distribution =>Sale Order => Report => Pick list and show me your format screen please thanks you

Comment: See my edit for detailed instructions on how to manually change Width/Height of report. Note that you have to set PrintAtBottom for the sections that you want at the bottom of the page, otherwise they will sit just below previous section.